# How to display a fixed code snippet on the website using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to display a fixed javascript code without running on my website. I only need to display it and not have it run. I am using react as the application. I researched online and I saw the way to do it is using the pre tag. But when I include the code within the pre tag, I think the open close curly brackets are causing an error. I am not sure how else to display a fixed code snippet using react. There are a lot of open close brackets in the code and I will not be able to use `` everywhere. Is there any other way to implement this? I have included my code below to show what I mean.

```js
<pre className={styles.rawExampleSectionCode}>
                                                {
                                                    "objectType": "list",
                                                    "uri": "",
                                                    "data": [
                                                        {
                                                        "id": "57dafe43317467e7b0ef5276",
                                                        "projectId": "54c17e92e4b0bc49e27d9398",
                                                        "number": 5,
                                                        "startingUserId": "57a28b28961401f240812caf",
                                                        "queued": 1473969731915,
                                                        "started": 1473969754283,
                                                        "completed": 1473969762970,
                                                        "status": "Succeeded",
                                                        "commitId": "1c6e8aa47951e39f9a905f0077af9355c35b712b",
                                                        "executor": "us-west-2:i-007942020ce7baeb5",
                                                        "outputCommitId": "73fe9481fe635bada713246c3c739beefa424e8c",
                                                        "title": "Run with great R^2 of 1!",
                                                        "isArchived": false,
                                                        "postProcessedTimestamp": 1473969767822,
                                                        "diagnosticStatistics": {
                                                            "isError": false,
                                                            "data": [
                                                            {
                                                                "key": "R^2",
                                                                "value": "1.000"
                                                            }
                                                            ]
                                                        },
                                                        "isCompleted": true,
                                                        "hardwareTierId": "gpu"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                    }
               </pre>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost had it, just make the object a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and then inject it into a [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) element within your JSX. Now it will display as expected in the React component.

```js
const obj = `{
    "objectType": "list",
    "uri": "",
    "data": [
        {
        "id": "57dafe43317467e7b0ef5276",
        "projectId": "54c17e92e4b0bc49e27d9398",
        "number": 5,
        "startingUserId": "57a28b28961401f240812caf",
        "queued": 1473969731915,
        "started": 1473969754283,
        "completed": 1473969762970,
        "status": "Succeeded",
        "commitId": "1c6e8aa47951e39f9a905f0077af9355c35b712b",
        "executor": "us-west-2:i-007942020ce7baeb5",
        "outputCommitId": "73fe9481fe635bada713246c3c739beefa424e8c",
        "title": "Run with great R^2 of 1!",
        "isArchived": false,
        "postProcessedTimestamp": 1473969767822,
        "diagnosticStatistics": {
            "isError": false,
            "data": [
            {
                "key": "R^2",
                "value": "1.000"
            }
            ]
        },
        "isCompleted": true,
        "hardwareTierId": "gpu"
        }
    ]
}`;

const Snippet = () => {
    return (
        <pre>
            <code>{obj}</code>
        </pre>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(<Snippet />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
pre {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-width: 80ch;
}

pre code {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: pre;
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</body>
```